# Working with combo boxes in power apps to concatenate onto items list

Tags: combobox, concatenation, powerapps

I have a table with many client names in it. I am using the distinct client names list as the items in my combo box. Is it possible to add in the number of times that client name has been listed in the original table next to the name of the client in the combo box in power apps? For example it will only appear once in the list on my combo box as i am using a distinct function but i would like to concatenate on in the number of times that client name appears in the original table?

```
ForAll(
    Distinct(
        Filter(client, StartsWith(name, Self.SearchText) && REVIEWED = 1),
        ultimatename
    ),
    Concatenate(
        Result & " (" & CountRows(
            Filter(client, name = Result && REVIEWED = 1)
        ) & ")" & Char(10)
    )
)
```

client is my table and name is the name i would like in my items in combo box

Comment: U can use `GroupBy` along with the `count` function, by default it will give you district values as well as the frequency of each distinct value.

Comment: This will help you: https://www.matthewdevaney.com/powerapps-collections-cookbook/group-by-and-find-the-count/